# Select parents which don't have a child with specific value

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-5.6

Let's image we have two tables:
PARENT (`id` INT) and CHILD (`parent_id` INT, `priority` INT)

We have 3 parents and its childs:

> Parent_1 (id: 1) with Child_1 (priority: 1)
>
> Parent_2 (id: 2) with Child_2 (priority: null)
>
> Parent_3 (id: 3) with Child_3 (priority: 1) and Child_4 (priority: null)

I've tried to use this SQL:

```
SELECT `parents`.* FROM `parents` LEFT OUTER JOIN `childs` ON `childs`.`parent_id` = `parent`.`id` WHERE `parents`.`id` IN (1, 2, 3) AND (childs.priority != 1 OR childs.priority IS NULL)
```

So I expect the result to select Parent_2 only because a check for `childs.priority != 1` applies here and check `childs.priority IS NULL` applies here also, but it outputs also Parent_3 because Child_4 passes check `childs.priority IS NULL`, but it shouldn't show up, because Child_3 doesn't pass `childs.priority != 1` this check

Comment: Can you explain the logic you want to implement?  Do you want parents that have a child with priority 1 or that don't have a child with priority 1?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM `parents`
WHERE `id` IN ( 1, 2, 3 )
  AND `id` NOT IN ( SELECT DISTINCT `parent_id` FROM `childs` WHERE `childs`.`priority` = 1 )
```

Firstly select the parent ID's of children with `priority` value of 1. Then select the parents, whose ID is not on the list...

Answer (score 0):

You're doing a left outer join so all parents will show up regardless.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this :

```
SELECT `parents`.* FROM `parents` WHERE `parents`.`id` IN (1, 2, 3) AND NOT IN ( SELECT `parents`.`id` JOIN `childs` ON `childs`.`parent_id` = `parent`.`id` WHERE childs.priority IS NOT NULL AND childs.priority = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `not exists`.  Your logic is a little hard to follow.  The following returns parents that have no child with priority 1:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM parents p
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM childs c 
                  WHERE c.parent_id = p.id AND
                        c.priority = 1
                 ) AND
      p.id IN (1, 2, 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fun way. It may also be the fastest.

```
Select distinct p.parentID

FROM parents p

except

Select distinct c.parentID

FROM childs c

WHERE c.priority = 1
```